# How to embed Python code in a fish script?

Tags: python, fish

I'm trying to convert over a Bash script that includes the following commands:

```
PYCODE=$(cat << EOF
#INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE
EOF
)

RESPONSE=$(COLUMNS=999 /usr/bin/env python3 -c "$PYCODE" $@)
```

The idea being that a `sed` find/replace is then used to inject an arbitrary Python script where `#INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE` is, creating the script that is then ran.

The corresponding Fish command would seem to be something like this

```
set PYCODE "
#INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE
"

set RESPONSE (COLUMNS=999 /usr/bin/env python3 -c "$PYCODE" $argv)
```

but this falls apart when you have a Python script that can include both `'` and `"` (and any other valid) characters.

What is the correct way to handle translate this use of `EOF`?

As a side note, I would prefer not to modify the `sed` command that is injecting the python code, but for reference here it is:

```
set FISH_SCRIPT (sed -e "/#INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE/r $BASE_DIR/test_sh.py" $BASE_DIR/../src/mfa.fish)
```

Comment: FYI, You're talking about a POSIX ["here-document"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). The `EOF` can be any string and here-docs have their own problems. I'm also assuming your sed example actually looks like `sed -e "/$PYCODE/r $BASE_DIR/test_sh.py" since it otherwise looks like the use of a here-doc is irrelevant. Finally, if the "#INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE" can contain a slash then your sed command will break. In other words, your existing code is extremely fragile.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> PYCODE=$(cat << EOF
> #INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE
> EOF
> )
> ```

This style of representing a string is called a heredoc. Fish does not support heredocs, [and details alternatives here](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html#heredocs).

> The corresponding Fish command would seem to be something like this
>
> ```
> set PYCODE "
> #INSERT_PYTHON_CODE_HERE "
> ```
>
> but this falls apart when you have a Python script that can include both ' and "

No it doesn't - you just need to escape quotes with a backslash like so:

```
# with single quotes
set -l py '
import os
print("There\'s no place like:")
print(os.getenv(\'HOME\'))
'
python3 -c $py

# with double quotes
set -l py "
import os
print(\"There's no place like:\")
print(os.getenv('HOME'))
"
python3 -c $py
```

If you have a long enough script where escaping the quotes is a problem, consider saving your script off to a file. After all, shells are really good at dealing with files.

If you absolutely want to have something resembling a HEREDOC in Fish, you could always pick some unique comment prefix like '###>', prefix your python script with that, and read that into a variable like so:

```
# Makeshift heredoc
###> import os
###> print("There's no place like:")
###> print(os.getenv('HOME'))

set -l py (grep "^###>" (status -f) | cut -c 6- | string collect)
python3 -c $py
```